# change stylesheet rule selector dynamically

Tags: javascript, styles

*This is a simplified version of how to dynamically change a selector rule:*

http://jsfiddle.net/vsync/SaQy6/

**For a giver inline style:**

```
<style type='text/css' id='myStyle'>
    ul > li{}
</style>
```

**trying to change the selector**

```
var styleTag = document.querySelector('#myStyle');
// the style sheet in the style tag
var sheet = styleTag.sheet ? styleTag.sheet : styleTag.styleSheet,
    // the first rule in the style sheet
    rules = sheet.cssRules ? sheet.cssRules : sheet.rules;

rules[0].selectorText = 'ul > li:nth-child(2)';
rules[0].style.cssText = 'background:red';
```

Nor `selectorText` or `cssText` work to set the selector dynbamically.

Then I read on MDN that `selectorText` is readOnly, and I am lost as to how should I actually change the selector without having to remove the whole style element and creating a new one. 
There is the option of removing the rule completely and inserting a new rule, but it's very non-standard. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/vsync/SaQy6/6/

**cross-browser way:**

```
var styleTag = document.querySelector('#myStyle');
// the style sheet in the style tag
var sheet = styleTag.sheet ? styleTag.sheet : styleTag.styleSheet,
    rules = sheet.cssRules ? sheet.cssRules : sheet.rules;

if( sheet.cssRules ){
    sheet.deleteRule(0); // deletes a rule at index 0
    sheet.insertRule("ul > li:nth-child(2n){background:red}", 0);
}
else{
    sheet.removeRule(0); // deletes a rule at index 0
    sheet.addRule("ul > li:nth-child(2n)", 'background:red', 0);
}
```

Comment: This works fine if there is only one style rule, but how common is that?  In general, keeping track of which index is which rule, if there are a number of them that should be dynamic, is hard. Rules are not named by default, and there seems to be no provision for naming them. The only naming scheme I see is to make a separate style sheet for each dynamic rule, with an id, and then this technique works fine.

Comment: @Victoria - so you can just delete all of them and re-insert. if you have 10 rules, just loop and delete 10 times..it's the only solution I can think of right now

Comment: yes, if all 10 rules are known, and in a known style block, that would work. Modular code may not know all 10 rules, though. So giving each rule a name in a separate <script id="name"> tag might be easier to manage in a modular fashion.

Comment: @Victoria - I have no idea what you are talking about..I am using my code in a jQuery plugin that handles many instances without a problem. you do not need to know the rules at all, it's an array, you just delete all the items and add anything you want.

Comment: Yes it is just an array, and as long as you keep a copy of the whole array somewhere, so you can edit it "off style sheet", then you can do as you say, just delete all the old ones and add all the current ones from the array. If several different modules were trying to maintain their own subset of the style sheet, then knowing which rules are which matters and is hard... so it would be better for each module to keep its own style sheet (with its own name). Does that make my comment clearer?

Comment: @Victoria - I do exactly like you say, I many styles like this on a page and each instance knows which is his, you just save a reference upon creation..I could theoretically have a thousand and there will be no mess what-so-ever, because I have `this.style` on each instance which points to the right `style` tag, always.

Comment: Just found [this](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Totally_Pwn_CSS_with_Javascript) which could be interesting to anyone reading this question.