# Is there a getElementById for style rules?

Tags: javascript, css

Short question is all in the title.... TL;DR below.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23572766/change-stylesheet-rule-selector-dynamically) and the comments talk about using the id on a style sheet containing a single rule as a clever technique for isolating styles that must change significantly, and works for changing both the selector and the style content.

A case that seems like it would be more frequent to me would be just to change the content, and that can be done by referencing the cssRule.style.properties ... if the correct cssRule can be located.

But individual style rules don't seem to have provision for an id, or a way to locate them among the (sometimes) hundreds of style rules in a style sheet (or collection of style sheets).

[this link](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Totally_Pwn_CSS_with_Javascript) talks about how to locate a rule by the selector text, but it seems one must match the selector text exactly, and that the implementation only finds the first rule with that selector text, although there could be more than one. The last one might be more useful to find, if the desire is to change a visible style.  Obviously the code could be tweaked to return the last, or to return an array... but sometimes the selector text gets atrociously long, too.

Having a way to flag the particular rule that wants to be changed dynamically would seem to be useful. If the stylesheet is manipulated, keeping the array index would be a brittle, bug-susceptible way of finding it.

Comment: No, you cannot do this.

Comment: Sometimes an example is better then a long text where the essential informations are hidden between the lines. My comment to how I interpret your question:  In modern browser (older IE create multiple rules if they have multiple selectors)  the selectors of the rules are left untouched. As of that you can always do `#my-id-i-only-use-for-searching-123, .the-actual select .or { color: black }` and then you could search for all rules having the selector `#my-id-i-only-use-for-searching-123`.

Comment: No, the question in the title does not make sense. Explain what you want to do with style sheet rules, instead of asking whether you can apply to them something that clearly does not apply (`getElementById` gets an element by its `id` attribute value, and `id` attributes are a markup language concept; CSS is not a markup language).

Comment: @t.niese -- I think you nailed it. If I still think so in the morning, I'll write up the code for an answer, unless you want to beat me to it... it is your idea.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela The question makes sense by analogy.... you fully understand how getElementById works; I'm looking for that similar concept, of having an id for something and searching for it. That concept transcends the specifics of the fact that CSS is not a markup language. id _is_ implemented in some, but not all, markup languages, but also in other realms such as employee id... employees are not a markup language either, just like CSS is not a markup language.

Comment: Questions like “is there something analogous to X in Y?” are far too vague for SO, especially when not accompanied with a description of *what you actually want to do and in which context*. Of course, since you cannot assign an identifier to a CSS rule, it is somewhat pointless to ask how you would *use* it, but the intended use might help to see the problem that you are trying to solve (we now see only an assumed part of a solution, and an impossible one).

Comment: Not sure if this will help you, but look at `window.getMatchedCSSRules`.

Comment: @torazaburo Thanks for the reference, but it seems getMatchedCSSRules isn't particularly cross-browser, nor standard, and current discussions between webkit and mozilla developers seem to favor removing it. Interesting reading, in the various issues I found for that API, though.

Comment: Reading both questions, I don't understand how this is useful.  Additionally, it seems like a very very poor choice to couple javascript to css.  I tend to [Decouple My HTML, CSS, and JavaScript](http://philipwalton.com/articles/decoupling-html-css-and-javascript/).

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela You may have thought the question didn't make sense, and too vague for SO, but t.niese properly interpreted and understood it and provided a good solution, all in less than a day. SO is great!

Comment: @ErikPhilips Agreed. But as the _very interesting_ article you referenced points out early on... There will always be some coupling between HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. For better or for worse, these technologies were built to interact with each other.  ... and my goal here is to make necessary coupling easier to achieve.

Comment: @Victoria Here's how I see it.  HTML is not not coupled to CSS or Javascript, HTML still works.  CSS is coupled to HTML, it does not produce anything without it.  Javascript is similar in the web experience.  Javascript can be indirectly coupled to CSS (`.addClass()` or `.removeClass()`) etc.  However there are no CSS rules possible that would couple CSS to Javascript.  However, this question appears to want Javascript to be coupled to CSS rules which seems to complicate what is coupled.

Comment: @ErikPhilips If I can find a few CSS rules, and they will be marked with IDs so it is obvious they might be tweaked, and tweak them, it saves finding the many elements that are referenced by those rules, and changing them individually. So a little coupling from JS->CSS saves lots of coupling from JS->HTML. Some of the cases are for user-specified styles (themes), and others are for data-determined styles (sizes of things that need to be the same, but the the actual value is determined by the particular data set, rather than the code). I try really hard not to write JS at all...

Answer (score 0):

No getElementById is only for js , in a stylesheet you call the id with the help of interpolation meaning you have a div whose id is myContainer, in your stylesheet you just need to declare #myContainer to give it styling accordingly

Comment: My question is how to find the css rule uniquely using javascript, not how to make the css rule apply to particular elements. I think I understand the basics of selector usage.

Comment: *"No getElementById is only for js"* - Yes, the OP understands that, and wants to know if there's an equivalent function that can be used to access parts of the style sheet similar to the way `getElementById` can access parts of the DOM.

Comment: getElementById is for js itself true, now you want to give this id a particular styling in script you can do it help of jquery by using .css if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, then my assumption of the comment was right.

You would have different possibilities to *mark*/*group* your rules if you want to find them easily.

You can not used `#id` and the possibility to have multiple selectors for a rule to introduce some structure.

The order in which the rule appear in `.cssRule` has to be the order they appear in the document. As of that you can mark a block of rules with a `#begin#id {}` and `#end#id {}`, or marking an individual rule by adding `#tag#id` to its selectors.

You e.g. could do something like this (But be award that I only tested the idea current FF and Chrome, don't know how IE will behave)

```js
var styles = document.styleSheets;
  
function findRulesInBlock(styleSheet, id) {
    var inBlock = false;
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < styleSheet.cssRules.length; i++) {
        if (styleSheet.cssRules[i].selectorText == '#begin#' + id) {
            inBlock = true;
        } else if (styleSheet.cssRules[i].selectorText == '#end#' + id) {
            inBlock = false;
        } else if (inBlock) {
            result.push(styleSheet.cssRules[i]);
        } else if(styleSheet.cssRules[i].selectorText.match('#tag#'+id)) {
            result.push(styleSheet.cssRules[i]);
        }
    }
    return result;
}


for (var i = 0; i < styles.length; i++) {
    var result = findRulesInBlock(styles[i], 'id123');
    for( var j=0 ; j<result.length; j++ ) {
    
        console.log(result[j].selectorText);
    }
}
```

```css
 rule1 {
    color: black;
}

/* the start of a block of rules*/
#begin#id123 {}

   .rule2 {
       color: black;
   }
   .rule3 {
       color: black;
   }

#end#id123 {}
/* the end of a block of rules*/

.rule4 {
    color: black;
}

#tag#id123, .rule5 {
    color: black;
}

#tag#id123, .rule6 {
    color: black;
}
```

Comment: Code looks very interesting, but clicking "Run code snippet" produces nothing... I pasted into into a local file, but also produced no output whether I put the <script> in the <head> or <body>.

Comment: @Victoria In which browser did you "Run code snippet"?

Comment: Firefox. Hmm. Thought I said that earlier, but it didn't show in what got posted. Sorry.

Comment: @Victoria I update the sample to only use `console.log` making sure that the `document.write` is not the problem. Works well here in FF 35. But as I said it is just a proof of concept code to illustrate how it could be achieved.  You probably have installed an extension that adds a stylesheet and accessing this might result in an error. Do you see some error message in the console?

Comment: Still produces nothing in the output box, not even in the console when looking at this page. But now a local copy produces output on the console.

Comment: Based on t.niese's idea and early code, my partner created [this](http://nevcal.com/temporary/test-css.html) since the SO snippet engine apparently interferes with this sort of code... I tried posting it as a snippet but it didn't work, so abandoned that.  This only does individual rule lookups, but has a more option that returns indexes that can be used to read the rules between two individual rule lookups if desired. Thanks for the help, t.niese.

Comment: @Victoria Great that I was able to help you. Beside that the snipped engine might interfere, such a code needs clean development api/structure definition, and various browser testing, which is out of the scope of a SO answer anyway. Btw i used `#tag#someid` the will never  match an element, as elements can only have one id, but I did not check in the specs if it is a valid selector. (W3C at least does not report an error)